# Why is Chubby lockserver not multi-master?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, paxos

As I understand Chubby at any given time there are 5 chubby servers. One is the master and handles coordination of writes to the quorum, and the other 4 servers are read only and forward handling of writes to the master. Writes use Paxos to maintain consistency.

Can someone explain to me why there is a distinction between the master and the 4 replicas. Why isn't Chubby multi-master? This question could also apply to Zookeeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a single master is more efficient because nodes don't have to deal with as much contention.

Both Chubby and Zookeeper implement a distributed state-machine where the point of the system is to decide a total ordering on transitions from one state to the next. It can take a lot of messages (theoretically infinite messages) to resolve a contention when multiple nodes are proposing a transition at the same time.

Paxos (and thus Chubby) uses an optimization called a "distinguished leader" where the replicas forward writes to the distinguished leader to reduce contention. (I am assuming Chubby replicas do this. If not they could, but the designers merely push that responsibility to the client.) Zookeeper does this too.

Both Chubby and Zookeeper actually *do* handle multiple leaders because they must deal with a leader that doesn't know it has died and then comes back from the dead. For Chubby, this is the whole point of using Paxos: eventually one of the leaders will win. (Well theoretically it may not, but we engineers do practical things like randomized backoff to make that probability tolerably small.) Zookeeper, on the other hand, assigns a non-decreasing id to each leader; and any non-current leader's transitions are rejected. This means that when a leader dies, Zookeeper has to pause and go through a reconfiguration phase before accepting new transitions.